# ffmpeg - как установить на хостинг?

Tags: python, discord, ffmpeg, hosting

Сегодня решил поставить своего дискорд бота на хостинг, как я могу установить ffmpeg, никак не получается.

Хостинг вида указанного на изображении: [image: Хостинг]

Comment: На такой вряд ли что-то можно поставить, хорошо еще если python модули можно, тогда поискать какой-нибудь который использует `ffmpeg` может подтянет его, но я таких модулей не знаю, ну и все равно `ffmpeg` это программа для ее запуска нужны соответсвующие права, которые вряд ли кто даст.

Comment: Задайте этот вопрос в техподдержку хостинга. Там людям точно не придется гадать как это сделать :)